# Django multiple templates

Tags: python, html, django

I'm building a site where users can view their posts [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6GMV.png). After building the quizzes portion, I tabbed to "blogs" where I realized I needed to import the blogs template to use it.

I'm using the quiz template already like this 
`{% extends '../main/base.html' %} {% block title %}View Quizzes{% endblock %} {% block content %}`

but I need to access the blog template as well. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can include the blog template into the main one like:

```
{% include "path/to/blogs.html" %}
```

It's best to have a main template which includes blogs, quizzes... (instead of inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

[You don't need django to do this.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_full_page_tabs.asp)